# Getting a 403 Client Error using tinys3 python package

Tags: python, amazon-s3

I'm getting a 403 Client Error when making an S3 connection on one of our production servers using the tinys3 python package. Any ideas? I think the credentials are right, as this script runs on my local machine without issue.

I'm getting the same issue on a test script I wrote to help debug this. Pasted below:

```
import tinys3 as s3

S3_ACCESS_KEY = "[redacted]"`
S3_SECRET_KEY = "[redacted]"
bucket = "test-bucket"
s3_image_prefix = "http://s3.amazonaws.com/" + bucket + "/"
conn = s3.Connection(S3_ACCESS_KEY, S3_SECRET_KEY, default_bucket=bucket)
conn.get('test_file.gif', bucket)
```

And the error:

```
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: http://s3.amazonaws.com/test-bucket/test_file.gif
```

Comment: Maybe try changing `s3_image_prefix` to `https` instead of `http`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the machine's system clock is more than 15 minutes behind, you can get this error. The time is put into the request and checked by Amazon. Check the system time with the `date` command.

This has been discussed by some other questions:

- [Amazon S3 403 AccessDenied error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24433198/amazon-s3-403-accessdenied-error)
- [Getting boto.exception.S3ResponseError: S3ResponseError: 403 Forbidden when uploading file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26594944/getting-boto-exception-s3responseerror-s3responseerror-403-forbidden-when-uplo/27984752#27984752)

Comment: Thanks! This was it. The machine clock on that server was about ~20 minutes behind.